# Terraform override aws_iam_policy_document in resource

Tags: terraform

I have a module for creating SQS Queue in Terraform.

This is what my main.tf looks like under modules/sqs:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "my_policy" {
  statement {
    sid = ""
    effect  = "Allow"
    actions = ["sqs:SendMessage"]
    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["sns.amazonaws.com"]
    }
    resources = ["arn:aws:sqs:us-west-2:123456:${var.sqs_queue_name}"]
    condition {
      test     = "ArnEquals"
      variable = "aws:SourceArn"
      values   = ["${var.sns_arn}"]
    }

  }

  version = "2008-10-17"
}

resource "aws_sqs_queue" "my_queue" {
  name                      = var.sqs_queue_name
  receive_wait_time_seconds = var.receive_wait_time_seconds
  visibility_timeout_seconds = var.visibility_timeout_seconds
  message_retention_seconds = var.message_retention_seconds
  max_message_size = var.max_message_size
  delay_seconds = var.delay_seconds
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.my_policy.json
}
```

and on my root main.tf I have this. Which works just fine, I'm able to create the queue.

```
module "aws_sqs_my_queue" {
  source = "./modules/sqs"

  sqs_queue_name = "MyQueue"
  receive_wait_time_seconds = 20
  visibility_timeout_seconds = 60
  sns_arn = "${module.aws_sns_my_topic.sns_arn}"
}
```

Now my problem is that I have to set up a Dead Letter Queue for `aws_sqs_my_queue` and the DLQ has a different Access Policy than what is set up on my data source `my_policy`. How can I set up another queue that has a different Access Policy but uses `my_queue` resource to create the SQS Queue.

My terraform version is v0.12.0

Answer (score 0):

Usually a default SQS policy for a DLQ is enough:

```
data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}

data "aws_region" "current" {}

resource "aws_sqs_queue" "dlq" {

  name = "my-dlq"

  policy = <<-EOL
  {
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Sid": "__owner_statement",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
          "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:root"
        },
        "Action": "SQS:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:${data.aws_region.current.name}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:my-dlq"
      }
    ]
  }
  EOL

}
```

Comment: I do agree, I am using the default policy for my DLQ, but the problem is I have another queue that needs to give access to an SNS topic and that's where the difference comes from.